# django-fsm: Permissions not raising exception

Tags: django, django-fsm

I've got source and target rule-based transition decorators working well in [django-fsm](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm) (Finite State Machine). Now I'm trying to add permissions handling. This seems straightforward, but it seems that no matter what I do, the transition is executed, regardless the user's permissions or lack thereof. I've tried with Django permission strings, and I've tried with `lambda`, per the documentation. I've tried all of these:

```
@transition(field=state, source='prog', target='appr', permission='claims.change_claim')
```

and

```
@transition(field=state, source='prog', target='appr', permission=lambda instance, user: not user.has_perm('claims.change_claim'),)
```

and, just as a double-check, since `permission` should respond to any callable returning True/False, simply:

```
@transition(field=state, source='prog', target='appr', permission=False)
def approve(self):
```

Which *should* raise a `TransitionNotAllowed` for all users when accessing the transition. But nope - even basic users with no permissions can still execute the transition (`claim.approve()`).

To prove that I've got permission string right:

```
print(has_transition_perm(claim.approve, request.user))
```

prints False. I am doing validation as follows (works for source/target):

```
class ClaimEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    Some users can transition claims through allowable states
    '''

    def clean_state(self):
        state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        if state == 'appr':
            try:
                self.instance.approve()
            except TransitionNotAllowed:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Claim could not be approved")
        return state

    class Meta:
        model = Claim
        fields = (
            'state',
        )
```

and the view handler is the standard:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    claim_edit_form = ClaimEditForm(request.POST, instance=claim)
    if claim_edit_form.is_valid():  # Validate transition rules
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the `permission` property does validation differently from the source/target validators. Rather than the decorator raising errors, you must evaluate the permissions established in the decorator elsewhere in your code. So to perform permission validation from a form, you need to pass in the user object, receive user in the form's `init`, and then compare against the result of `has_transition_perm`. So this works:

```
# model
@transition(field=state, source='prog', target='appr', permission='claims.change_claim')
def approve(self):
....

# view
if request.method == "POST":
    claim_edit_form = ClaimEditForm(request.user, request.POST, instance=claim)
        ....

# form
from django_fsm import has_transition_perm

class ClaimEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    Some users can transition claims through allowable states
    (see permission property on claim.approve() decorator)
    '''

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        # We need to pass the user into the form to validate permissions
        self.user = user
        super(ClaimEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_state(self):
        state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        if state == 'appr':
            if not has_transition_perm(self.instance.approve, self.user):
                raise forms.ValidationError("You do not have permission for this transition")
```